# R - How to pass date as a argument in the SQL query

Tags: sql, r

I tried this following query:

```
studentcal3 <- function(x,y)
{
i<- x
print(i)
j <- y
 print(j)
demo1 <-sqldf("SELECT a.StudentName, (b.marks/a.marks) as difference from 
(select Date, StudentName, marks from studenthistorydemo WHERE Date= i) as a 
INNER JOIN (select Date, StudentName, marks from studenthistorydemo where 
 Date= j) as b on a.marks= i and b.marks= j  WHERE a.marks = i and b.marks = 
j and a.StudentName=b.StudentName")
 }
```

And then called the function

```
studentcal3('2014-01-01','2014-01-02')
```

Error:- Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : no such column: i

How to resolve this?
P.S - I'm new to R

Comment: Look at bquote function

Answer (score 0):

How should the engine know, which parts are external variables? You must use string concatenation ([Read about `paste()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/paste.html)). And be aware, that you have to pass your variables within single quotes and in a culture and language independant format!

```
  studentcal3 <- function(x,y)
  {
    i<- x
    print(i)
    j <- y
    print(j)
    cmd <-paste("SELECT a.StudentName, (b.marks/a.marks) as difference from ", 
                  "(select Date, StudentName, marks from studenthistorydemo WHERE Date='",i,"') as a ",
                  "INNER JOIN (select Date, StudentName, marks from studenthistorydemo where ", 
                  "Date='",j,"') as b on a.marks='",i,"' and b.marks='",j,
                  "' WHERE a.marks ='",i,"' and b.marks ='",j,"' and a.StudentName=b.StudentName",sep="")
    #demo1 <-sqldf(cmd)
    print(cmd)
  }
  studentcal3('2014-01-01','2014-01-02')
```

The result

> "SELECT a.StudentName, (b.marks/a.marks) as difference from (select
>   Date, StudentName, marks from studenthistorydemo WHERE
>   Date='2014-01-01') as a INNER JOIN (select Date, StudentName, marks
>   from studenthistorydemo where Date='2014-01-02') as b on
>   a.marks='2014-01-01' and b.marks='2014-01-02' WHERE a.marks
>   ='2014-01-01' and b.marks ='2014-01-02' and a.StudentName=b.StudentName"

And be aware of sql injection! You might build a statment with real parameters to avoid injection attacks.

If this statement really delivers what you expect is another question. You might print it out and paste it into a query window to test it first...

Comment: Thanks for the time @Shnugo. It didn't worked. Can you demonstrate or share some lights about how you proceed with your mentioned query?

Comment: @BTG123 This question is about *how to pass the argument into the sql command*. Is **this question** solved? Check this with a copy of the statement and execute it directly against your database (which RDBMS? Please tag appropriately, `[sql]` is not enough!). If it's solved please close this question (acceptance check below the vote counter) and start a new question. On StackOverflow we follow the principle *one issue - one question*...

Comment: Thnaks @Shnugo. I'll keep that in mind. You been a great help!. Cheers.